# SIFT feature detector produces unhandled exception

Tags: opencv, sift

The code below is just to see feature detection in SIFT. The problem is that it breaks when I run it.

```
#include <features2d.hpp>
#include <stdafx.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cv.hpp>
#include <cxcore.hpp>
#include <highgui.h>
#include <iostream>


using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    Mat img = imread("c:\\chappal.jpg", 0);
    Ptr<FeatureDetector> feature_detector = FeatureDetector::create("SIFT");
    vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;

    feature_detector->detect(img, keypoints);

    Mat output;

    drawKeypoints(img, keypoints, output, Scalar(255, 0, 0));

    namedWindow("meh", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    imshow("meh", output);
    waitKey(0);



    return 0;
}
```

When debugged step by step the program breaks at this line:`feature_detector->detect(img, keypoints);`

I have checked it again and again and dont know what the problem might be caused by.

P.S. I first tried `SiftFeatureDetector` in place of `FeatureDetector::create("SIFT");` but got errors as in it could not find `SiftFeatureDetector` in the library file. I learned about both code samples from posts here on this forum.

Thank you

Comment: I found out that ``SiftFeatureDetector`` is now kept in a seperate library in the non-free folder. If so, why is the non-free library not used in this 2.4 tutorial : http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_detection/feature_detection.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you tried this, but since it is now in the nonfree.h library, you need to use the initModule_nonfree().  That solved the problem for me.